# Temporary file location where i save a query out put in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have an issue related to cron.
Suppose in a shell script,i'm running a query and the out put is getting stored to a temporary file. What is the location of that temporary file? and how can i delete in the shell script itself?

Comment: Well, you certainly know or somehow indicated the file to redirect output to, no..?

Comment: $ /path/to/your/script.sh > output.txt. I want to know where is this output.txt will be saved?

Answer (score 0):

> If a command cron is  running has output (e.g. status reports, or
>   errors), cron will email the output  to whoever is specified in the
>   MAILTO variable. If no one if specified, then the  output will be
>   mailed to the owner of the process that produced the output.

From [here](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

`output.txt` will end up in the directory the cron starts your command with.  Unfortunately, the POSIX crontab [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html) does not seem to specify what that directory is.  Neither could I find anything on that in the man pages on my system.

On my system cron will use the home directory of the user it runs the command as.  If you don't find `output.txt` there on your system, you can tease the directory out of cron by temporarily adding a line like the following to the crontab:

*For user crontabs:*

```
* * * * * pwd >>/tmp/cronpwd
```

*For the system crontab (replace `user` by the name of the user that ran the original command):*

```
* * * * * user pwd >>/tmp/cronpwd
```

Then wait a minute, and the file `/tmp/cronpwd` should appear, containing the name of the current directory of cron-commands.  Don't forget to remove the extra line from the crontab again!

Whatever the directory is, check that it is actually writable by the user running the script.  If it isn't then the output is lost and there is no way to get it back.

Note that it is probably a good idea to simply make the command independent of the current working directory, either by specifying absolute paths or by explicitly changing the current directory at the beginning of the command:

```
5 0 * * *        /path/to/your/script.sh > /where/it/should/go/output.txt
5 0 * * *        cd /where/it/should/go && /path/to/your/script.sh > output.txt
```

*(That example is a user's crontab, not the system crontab.)*